Trying to create chatbot on M1, vscode. Using chatterbot but getting errors with spacy
Hi I am trying to create a chatbot using chatterbot, any ideas on what I should do regarding the error?
my code:
///this is to just train the bot///


from chatterbot import ChatBot 
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer 

bot = ChatBot("chatbot", read_only = False, logic_adapters = ["chaetterbot.logic.BestMatch"])

list_to_train = [
                "Hi ",
                "Hi there ",
                "How are you? ",
                "Fine, thank you for asking ",
                "what's your name? ",
                "My name is chatbot ",
                "Who created you? ",
                "Ahh, good question, Majid is who created me ",
                "How old are you ",
                "I am ageless ",
                
]

list_trainer = ListTrainer(bot)

list_trainer.train(list_to_train)

error I am getting:

python3 -u "/Users/majid/Desktop/sampleB/chattt.py"
majid@MAJIDs-MacBook-Air sampleB % python3 -u
"/Users/majid/Desktop/sampleB/chattt.py" Traceback (most recent call
last):   File "/Users/majid/Desktop/sampleB/chattt.py", line 5, in

bot = ChatBot("chatbot", read_only = False, logic_adapters = ["chaetterbot.logic.BestMatch"])   File
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chatterbot/chatterbot.py",
line 28, in init
self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)   File
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chatterbot/utils.py",
line 33, in initialize_class
return Class(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chatterbot/storage/sql_storage.py",
line 20, in init
super().init(**kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chatterbot/storage/storage_adapter.py",
line 20, in init
self.tagger = PosLemmaTagger(language=kwargs.get(   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chatterbot/tagging.py",
line 13, in init
self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/init.py",
line 50, in load
return util.load_model(   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/util.py",
line 330, in load_model
raise IOError(Errors.E941.format(name=name, full=OLD_MODEL_SHORTCUTS[name])) OSError: [E941] Can't find model
'en'. It looks like you're trying to load a model from a shortcut,
which is obsolete as of spaCy v3.0. To load the model, use its full
name instead:
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
For more details on the available models, see the models directory:
https://spacy.io/models. If you want to create a blank model, use
spacy.blank: nlp = spacy.blank("en")

currently running python 3.8.0, I've had issues installing spacy but managed at the end 'I think'. I've downloaded chatterbot, chatterbot-corpus, Jupyter, flask, pyyaml, but when I tried to download: python -m space download en, it says command not found. im new to this and could use help please
